# HikariDataSource. Improve performance

Tags: hikaricp

I created a second DataSource in my application.

I created it with HikariDataSource, since I had problems because it was disconnected.

Now it does not disconnect, but it is very slow

My configuration is the following:

```
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://xxx/xxx_pm
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
        hikari:
            idle-timeout: 10000
```

java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasources.xxx")
public class DatabaseXXXConfiguration extends HikariConfig{

@Bean(name = "xxxDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    return new HikariDataSource(this);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to improve performance.

They are small queries of tables with pagination of about 25 records and takes 4 seconds.

I have observed that a query that is 200 records of a select, takes 46 seconds, before it did in 2 seconds.

Before, they were thousandth of seconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Extending HikariConfig and overriding getDataDource() is not a valid way to create a DataSource.  The HikariDataSource constructor is going to copy the HikariConfig into an immutable instance of HikariConfig, which will not include your overridden method.  I’m not sure what dynamics are occurring as a result, but you might end up with something that creates a new pool on every connection attempt.

Basically, don’t do this.  Pick a standard pattern of initialization that does not require extending HikariCP classes.